# ASP.NET MVC, Using a viewmodel with strongly typed helpers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a question about setting up a viewmodel when you use the strongly typed helpers (HTML.EditorFor, etc.) and a viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC.  I am working with MVC5, but I would imagine my question is also applicable to other versions.

For this example, I'm working with the create of the CRUD process.

In the example, the user enters the name and address of a person and city is selected from a drop down.

Here is the model:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("City")]
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string address {get; set;}

        //Navigational property
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the viewmodel:

```
public class PersonCreateViewModel
{
    public SelectList cities {get; set;}
    public Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Action Method from the controller used to pass back the view for the create page:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CreateViewModel viewmodel = new CreateViewModel();

        viewmodel.cities = new SelectList(db.Cities, "CityID", "name");
        return View(viewmodel);
    }
```

Here is part of my view:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.person.address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.address)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.person.CityID, "CityID", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("cities")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.person.CityID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I declare the model for my view as such:

```
@model TestProjects.ViewModels.PersonCreateViewModel
```

And Lastly, the http post method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="PersonID,CityID,nameaddress")] Person person)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Add to database here and return

        }

        //return back to view if invalid db save
        return View(person);
    }
```

So at one point I had all of this working.  Then I decided I wanted to use the ViewModel approach.  I still don't have it working, but here are some questions:

In the view, I reference the properties of the model with model.person.address.  Is this the proper way to do this?  I noticed that when it generates the html, it names the field person_address, etc.

So should I just change the Bind properties in the http post controller mehtod to reflect this?  But if I change this, the properties will no longer match up with the person object causing a disconnect.

Or should I change my view model?  And instead of having a person type in my ViewModel, copy/paste all of the fields from the model into the ViewModel?   I guess this would also work, but is that the typical way it is done?  It seems redundant to list out every property of the model when I could just have an instance if the model in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the view, I reference the properties of the model with model.person.address. Is this the proper way to do this? I noticed that when it generates the html, it names the field person_address, etc.

Yes, that is the correct way to reference model properties. More accurately, since `model` in your helper expressions is a reference to the `Func`'s input parameter, it could be anything. The following would work just as well:

```
@Html.EditorFor(banana => banana.person.address)
```

> So should I just change the Bind properties in the http post controller mehtod to reflect this? But if I change this, the properties will no longer match up with the person object causing a disconnect.

You don't need the bind parameters at all. What you should do is take all reference to your data entities (i.e. `Person`) out of your view model completely (otherwise using the view model is a little pointless as it's tightly coupled with your data entities anyway) and give the view model properties that the view needs, e.g.:

```
public class PersonCreateViewModel
{
    public SelectList Cities { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

They should then bind back by default to the same model, presuming your view is correct:

```
public ActionResult Create (PersonCreateViewModel model)
{
    // Map PersonCreateViewModel properties to Person properties
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks.  I think using your version of the ViewModel would give me the ability to use the Bind parameters or map them as in your action method example.

Comment: I noticed someone down voted this answer.  An explanation would be very helpful if someone has it.  Thanks!